# How to get image link from DistributionPublicUrl (outside Salesforce)?

Tags: files, contentdocument, contentdistribution

I need to display pictures outside salesforce so Im generating DistributionPublicUrl from ContentDistribution but the 'DistributionPublicUrl' its a page with the picture but its not the picture. Cant find the way to get just a link of the picture without any autogenerate bar. If I enter to DistributionPublicUrl and right click on the pic Im able to get the direct link but need to automate this.

DistributionPublicUrl
[image: DistributionPublicUrl]
This is what I need (direct link to the image without bars to display outside SF)
[image: This is what I need (direct link to the image without bars to display outside SF)]

Must be a way to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for people searching on this; there is a field called "ContentDownloadUrl" on the ContentDistribution object. Try to leverage that instead of "DistributionPublicUrl".

try this article: https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2021/05/04/generating-public-url-for-salesforce-files/